# Prevenir ou remediar?

Tags: php, syntax-error

Ultimamente tenho me preocupado demais em prevenir erros no código.
Contudo fiquei com essa duvida:

> É melhor verificar (prevenir) ou remediar (Garantir existência)?

Digamos que se tenha :

```
$var = array(
    'name' => 'Guilherme',
    'lastName' => 'Lautert'
);
```

Qual o ideal verificar se o índice existe ou garantir que ele exista?

#### Verificar

```
if(isset($var['name'])){
    # code ...
}
```

#### Garantir

```
$default = array(
    'name' => null,
    'lastName' => null,
);

$var = array(
    'name' => 'Guilherme',
);

$var = array_merge($default, $var);

$lastName = $var['lastName'];
```

#### Edição

Como comentado pode ficas baseado em opinião, então supondo uma situação :

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: APP + "/"+CONTROLADOR_ATUAL+"/jsonGetResposta",
    data: { cd : cd},
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(msg){
        jQuery('#vl_total').val(msg.dados.vlTotal);
        jQuery('#nr_total').val(msg.dados.nrTotal);
    }
});
```

Qual o ideal, garantir que o índice existe no PHP, ou verificar se `dados`, `vlTotal/nrTotal`, existe no JS?

Comment: Depende do caso. Os dois códigos não são equivalentes, então é difícil compará-los.

Comment: Votei pra fechar por achar que é baseada em opiniões. Já tem uma resposta que começa com "particularmente prefiro...."

Comment: Desculpe me pelo, particularmente, digo isso pois seguindo os padrões de usabilidade deve se sempre que possível retornar um feedback para o usuário, mas não sei onde pretende empregar o código. Creio que devem avaliar melhor antes de julgar uma pergunta. Obrigado.

Comment: `$var += ['nome' => 'Wallace de Souza']`

Comment: @bigown dependendo do caso, ele pode usar os dois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pergunta pode ser interpretada como baseada em opniões, pois, como diria um amigo meu: Tudo depende.

Você necessariamente precisa que os dados existam?
Então é necessário que os mesmos sejam avaliados devidamente.

Você quer tratá-los como valores opcionais? Então, utilize os valores padrões.

## implementações existentes

Em relação essa forma de utilizar esse `default values`(valores padrão), a utilização da mesma geralmente se dá quando um argumento ou um valor é opcional.

Nesse casos, é poderíamos nos lembrar dos parâmetros opcionais dados para algumas funções. Um valor `callable` por exemplo que pode ter o valor `null` por padrão.

Eu já vi alguns frameworks, como o `CakePHP 2`, que utilizam-se desse "valores padrões" para tratar um `array` como se fosse um `argumento  nomeado`. Vou mostrar um exemplo clássico em casos onde precisaria por exemplo de salvar dados de uma model, onde a data de criação é inserida automaticamente se a mesma não for passada.

Exemplo:

```
function saveData(array $data)
{
     $data += ['created_at' => new DateTime;];
   
}
```

Esses exemplo permitem fazer:

```
saveData(['name' => 'Wallace', 'created_at' => new DateTime('-1 day')]
```

ou

```
saveData(['name' => 'Wallace']);
```

Ainda falando sobre os `argumentos nomeados`, podemos ainda "misturar" o "previnir" com o "remediar".

Por exemplo:

```
 saveData(array $data)
 {
        $data += ['data' => new DateTime];

        if (! isset($data['name']) {
            throw new BadCallMethodException('É necessário passar "name"');
        }
 }
```

Então, há casos onde você vai ter que "previnir" (validar), e outros que vai querer "remediar" (tornar opcional).